# Ensuring quality of Magento 2 extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, coding-standards

Magento 2 comes with some tools to help developers create quality extensions.
What are the things that one should check before publishing an extension?
I have 3 for now:

- running the tests `bin/magento dev:tests:run`
- running php codesniffer with the [Ecg2 standard](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard) `phpcs --standard=EcgM2 path/to/code`
- make sure compilation works `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Anything else i can run to get information about what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add [Marketplace Upload Validator](https://alankent.me/2016/02/01/magento-2-marketplace-upload-validation-tool-quick-note/) to your checklist as well.

> The current version is a standalone PHP script that takes the Composer
>   package ZIP file(s) on the command line. Errors are reported to the
>   screen. Examples include a missing composer.json file, missing fields
>   in the composer.json file, and so on.

Script present [here](https://gist.github.com/alankent/fcf280dd9c599921b71d)

Comment: This validator only makes sense if you want to distribute via Marketplace. If you use a different distribution model (for example directly via github for an open source module this tool is not needed).

Comment: @KristofatFooman This script also validates your composer.json and folder structure file which is vital even if you are publishing it on GitHub and would like the option to provide extension downloadable via composer as well

Comment: The marketplace validation is stricter than what is doable with Composer and in particular doesn't handle additional folders for things like integration tests well. Agree with you that this script gives you some guidance on how to structure some elements of your composer.json but I would not consider the folder structure as the only way of working.